# Change Language in Visual Studio 2010 "Spell Checker"-Extension

Tags: visual-studio-2010, spell-checking

i'm searching for a way to change the language of the "Spell Checker"-Extension for Visual Studio 2010.

The problem is following:
I'm using the german language version of Visual Studio 2010. If I use the "Spell Checker"-Extension it checks the correctness in german language, while I'm coding in english.
So nearly every single word is underlinded as incorrect.

How can I change the checking language to english or how can I change the libary it used to check language?

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for the problem by myself.

If anybody like to know it:

1. First download the extension inside the Visual Studio extension-manager.
2. Second download the [source](https://github.com/NoahRic/Spellchecker) of the extension and open it in Visual Studio (Visual Studio SDK has to be installed to open the project)
3. Third navigate to Spellchecker/Spelling/SpellingTaggers.cs and add the following line inside the CheckSpellings method of SpellingTaggers class under the textBox initialization:

   textBox.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage("en-US");
4. Next build the dll-Files with Visual Studio
5. And finally replace the dll-files with those in the directory of the Spell Checker Extension (it can be found under %HOME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Extensions\Roman Golovin, Michael Lehenbauer, Noah Richards\Spell Checker\2.23 or something similar)

That's it!

If you want to use a language different from "en-US", change the Language Code.

Answer (score 2):

There is a fork of spellchecker, that maybe will eventually be integrated into the main branch, that supports spellchecking in multiple languages here:
https://github.com/simonegli8/Spellchecker

Simon Egli

Answer (score 1):

Remark:

Step 5 will not work in all cases. I think dlls are cached or something like this, so it would be better to uninstall spell checker from Visual Studio and reinstall the new compiled version of SpellChecker.vsix (could be found in SpellChecker.Implementation\bin...).
This worked for me.